# How would I use functions to make my code not as repetitive and more efficient?

Tags: python, function, if-statement

I've essentially written this `if` statement 9 times in a quiz game project for the 9 questions and answers I need. How would I define a function to potentially condense these `if` statements?

```
questionOne = input(listQuestions[0])
questionOneCasing = questionOne.title()
if questionOneCasing == "Quentin Tarantino":
  score = score + 1
  print("Correct, your score is " + str(int(score)) + "!")
else:

 print("Unfortanetely this is incorrect! Your score is " + str(int(score)) + ".")
```

Comment: Why not use dictionary to store question-answer pair and for each question just check if value matches the answer. `qna_dict[q_key]==ans_by_user`

Answer (score 0):

Use a list of dictionaries to separate logic from data. For example:

```
questions = [{"question": "Question 1... ?", "answer": "answer 1"},
             {"question": "Question 2... ?", "answer": "answer 2"},
             {"question": "Question 3... ?", "answer": "answer 3"},
             {"question": "Question 4... ?", "answer": "answer 4"},
] #todo rename fields if wanted

score = 0
for question in questions:
    given_answer = input(question["question"])
    if given_answer == question["answer"]: #todo refine check
        score += 1
    else:
        print("wrong answer")
    print("your score is {}".format(score))
```

Comment: In this case, a list of `('question', 'answer')` tuples would be more compact and readable. `for question, answer in questions:...`

Answer (score 0):

Start off with questions in this format:

```py
# Replace with actual questions and answers - add as many as you need
questions = [
    ('question 1', 'answer 1'),
    ('question 2', 'answer 2'),
    ('question 3', 'answer 3')
]
```

Then, using loops:

```py
score = 0
for q, a in questions:
    ans = input(q)
    if ans.lower() == a.lower(): # or whatever check you want
        score += 1
        print('Correct!\n')
    else:
        print('Wrong!\n')
print(f'You got {score} out of {len(questions)}!')
```

Or, using a recursive function:

```py
def check(qs, i=0):
    if i >= len(qs):
        return 0
    q, a = qs[i]
    ans = input(q)
    return (ans.lower() == a.lower()) + check(qs, i+1)

score = check(questions)
print(f'You got {score} out of {len(questions)}')
```

Answer (score -1):

You could also do something with a class like:

```
score = 0

class quizQuestion(self, question, answer)
    self.question
    self.answer
  def answerCorrectly(self)
    print("Correct!")
    score += 1
  def answerIncorrect(self)
    print("incorrect")
    score -= 1

quizQuestion("Who is luke's father?", "darth vader")

#So basically now all you would have to do is:

quizQuestionAnswer = input

if quizQuestionAnswer == answer:
    answerCorrect
```

Its something along those lines but you would have to polish it